# Probability - Balls in an Urn

Tags: probability

We have $28$ balls, $15$ yellow, $8$ blue and $5$ orange. 
You pick $6$ balls at random, without replacement.

Calculate the probability that the second ball chosen is orange, given that the last ball chosen is blue.

I'm confused, surely this condition doesn't make a difference?

Comment: Each time that you extract a ball, the probabilities for the color of the next changes cause the sample is without replacement.

Comment: It may be counterintuitive but the condition does make a difference.

Comment: For example if the second ball is blue then it's less likely the sixth ball is blue, than if the second was orange - because there are fewer blue balls to choose from in that case.

Comment: Actually, your intuition should be that the probability that the first one is orange is the same as the probability that the second is orange.

Comment: @sinbadh I thought the probability would be $\frac{23}{28} \times \frac{5}{27} + \frac{5}{28} \times \frac{4}{27}$?

Comment: @theman Almost, you want the conditional probabilities when given the last ball will be blue.  Reserve a ball.   $$\tfrac {22}{27}\times\tfrac 5{26}+\tfrac 5{27}\times\tfrac 4{26} = \tfrac{22+4}{26}\times\tfrac 5{27} = \tfrac 5{27}$$ As probablyme observed, the probability that the second ball will be orange is the same as the probability that the first ball will be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of thinking: to draw $6$ balls from a set $(15Y,18B,5O)$ knowing that the sixth ball is blue, is equivalent of drawing $5$ balls from a set $(15Y,17B,5O)$

Hence the probability is $5/27$

Another way of thinking: let $O_2$ be the event "second ball is orange", $B_6$ "sixth ball is blue". Then, using conditional probability:

$$P(O_2|B_6)=\frac{P(O_2  B_6)}{P(B_6)}=\frac{ 5/28\ \times  8/27 }{8/28}=\frac{5}{27}$$

Answer (score 0):

It does matter. After choosing a blue ball, you now have $27$ balls: $15$ yellow, $7$ blue, and $5$ orange since there was no replacement. Ergo, your probability of then choosing an orange ball is $\frac{5}{27}$ rather than $\frac{5}{28}$.